# JQuery баг в простом примере - почему ширина меняется после анимации?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

Изучаю JQuery, сделал простой тест но есть странный баг.

Есть две кнопки, при нажатии на которые див меняет свой стиль. Почему-то после нажатия зеленой кнопки, ширина дива "прыгает" к изначальному значению.

Почему это происходит и как это исправить?

```js
/*remove animate2 class and assign animate1 class to target*/

$(function() {
  $('#trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('#target').removeClass('animate2');
    $('#target').addClass('animate1');
  });
});

/*remove animate1 class and assign animate2 class to target*/

$(function() {
  $('#trigger2').on('click', function() {
    $('#target').removeClass('animate1');
    $('#target').addClass('animate2');
  });
});
```

```css
/*just a container around*/

#container {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border: solid green 1px;
}


/*green button*/

#trigger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 20px auto;
}


/*red button*/

#trigger2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 20px auto;
}


/*Target div which will be changing*/

#target {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}


/*Keyframes for green button*/

@keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    background: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background: blue;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
}


/*Keyframes for red button*/

@keyframes mysecond {
  0% {
    background: blue;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 0%;
  }
}


/*cusstom class to be assigned by green button*/

.animate1 {
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 3s;
  animation: myfirst 3s;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}


/*cusstom class to be assigned by red button*/

.animate2 {
  -webkit-animation: mysecond 3s;
  animation: mysecond 3s;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  border: solid red 1px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="trigger"></div>
  <div id="trigger2"></div>
  <div id="target"></div>
</div>
```

P.S. Буду благодарен за совет, все ли правильно в плане JQuery, или лучше что-то сделать иначе.

Answer (score 1):

Причина бага в том что ID приоритетом переписывает CLASS. Если заменить id на class проблема исчезает:

```js
/*remove animate2 class and assign animate1 class to target*/

$(function(){
  $('.trigger').on('click',function(){
   $('.target').removeClass('animate2');
      $('.target').addClass('animate1');
  });
 });

/*remove animate1 class and assign animate2 class to target*/

$(function(){
  $('.trigger2').on('click',function(){
          $('.target').removeClass('animate1');
   $('.target').addClass('animate2');
  });
 });
```

```css
/*just a container around*/

.container {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border: solid green 1px;
}

/*green button*/

.trigger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

/*red button*/

.trigger2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

/*Target div which will be changing*/

.target{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

/*Keyframes for green button*/

@keyframes myfirst {
    0% {
      background: white;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 0%;
    }
    100% {
      background: blue;
      width: 150px;
      border-radius: 100%;
    }
 }

/*Keyframes for red button*/

@keyframes mysecond {
    0% {
      background: blue;
      width: 150px;
      border-radius: 100%;
    }
    100% {
      background: white;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 0%;
    }
 }

/*cusstom class to be assigned by green button*/
 
.animate1 {
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 3s;
  animation: myfirst 3s;
   
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  }

/*cusstom class to be assigned by red button*/
 
.animate2 {
  -webkit-animation: mysecond 3s;
  animation: mysecond 3s;
   
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  border: solid red 1px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="trigger"></div>
  <div class="trigger2"></div>
  <div class="target"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас тоже что-то не то. При нажатии на красную кнопку граница красная, а не синяя, и в конце анимации квадрат прыгает со 100px ширины на 150px.

Answer (score 0):

У вас возникает конфликт приоритетов, тк ширина задается и в id и в классе. Конфликт можно исправить например использовав !important. И ещё в классе .animate2 ширина 100px должна быть.

```js
/*remove animate2 class and assign animate1 class to target*/

$(function() {
  $('#trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('#target').removeClass('animate2');
    $('#target').addClass('animate1');
  });
});

/*remove animate1 class and assign animate2 class to target*/

$(function() {
  $('#trigger2').on('click', function() {
    $('#target').removeClass('animate1');
    $('#target').addClass('animate2');
  });
});
```

```css
/*just a container around*/

#container {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border: solid green 1px;
}


/*green button*/

#trigger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 20px auto;
}


/*red button*/

#trigger2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 20px auto;
}


/*Target div which will be changing*/

#target {
  border: solid blue 1px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

/*Keyframes for green button*/

@keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    background: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background: blue;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
}


/*Keyframes for red button*/

@keyframes mysecond {
  0% {
    background: blue;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 0%;
  }
}


/*cusstom class to be assigned by green button*/

.animate1 {
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 3s;
  animation: myfirst 3s;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  width: 150px !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}


/*cusstom class to be assigned by red button*/

.animate2 {
  -webkit-animation: mysecond 3s;
  animation: mysecond 3s;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid red 1px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="trigger"></div>
  <div id="trigger2"></div>
  <div id="target"></div>
</div>
```